# How to Implement Google Analytics in SDL tridion web sites?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

My Options :

1. include the analytics code in page templates or CTs.
2. create a component contains the analytic code and render it in Comonent presentation of the page.

which could be better or please suggest any other way out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first approach is normally preferable, since it allows you to include information about a component or page in your call to Google Analytics. And you may not even have to write it yourself, since there is a free extension called the Web Analytics Enabler, which is available [here](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/enabler_google_analytics.aspx). I recommend that you check that out first.

Comment: The provided link is not working. I guess this is the link http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/googleanalytics.aspx or http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/enabler_google_analytics.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For analytics or any markup you're adding with SDL Tridion, you'll want to confirm the content model, authors, and consider how the content and templates may evolve.

### Content Model

Assuming a single instance across all pages, you can add ([per Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080)) to your page template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

### Authors

Authors would be developers in this case. But if you have SEO authors and multiple publications, consider adding the script via template, but the tracking code in a component field, referenced in your layout TBB:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '@@GoogleTrackingCode@@']);
```

Up to you on how to add GoogleTrackingCode to the package. Adjust as needed to your rendering framework or templating approach.

### Changes

If the script format may change frequently (doubt it), consider component fields for the script itself. It's more likely the business will want more-detailed link and campaign type tracking.

### More-Detailed Tracking

To add tracking codes for individual links ([Outbound links](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920&topic=1136919&ctx=topic)) or [custom tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables), place either at the page template (for non-dyanamic embedded component presentations) or from CTs. Just remember [components aren't unique on their own](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/01/sdl-tridion-and-web-analytics-aka-how.html).